# C++11 Delete Class Type?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 N3485 5.3.5.1 it says:

> The operand [of `delete`] shall be a pointer to object type **or a class type**.  If of class type, the operand is contextually converted to a pointer to object type.

What is an example of such usage (operand is of class type)?

Comment: Do you mean any example or example that shows it's useful?

Comment: Any will do, but useful is preffered.

Comment: Anybody knows, why wording changed between n3376 and n3485? Cannot find any related information...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If of class type, the operand is contextually implicitly converted to
>   a pointer to object type.

So, you can use `delete` on object, but when and only when this type has implicit conversion operator to pointer.

```
class A
{
public:
   class Inner {};
   A()
   {
      inner = new Inner();
   }
   operator Inner*() { return inner; }
private:
   Inner* inner;
};

int main()
{
   A* a = new A();
   delete *a;
   delete a;
}
```

However, it's not new feature of C++11, in C++03 standard there are almost same words

> The operand shall have a pointer
> type, or a class type having a single conversion function (12.3.2) to a pointer type.

Comment: Sometimes I wish the C++ standard would more... strict? regular? I don't see any gain from this behavior apart from pretending that a pointer wrapper *is* a pointer, as @riv mentioned (but that looks like a very, very leaky abstraction in general).